# Best Way to Install and Maintain the Dependency?

Tags: gcc, rpm, centos6, yum

I am a bit new to this kind of administration stuffs -- I would like to build GCC 4.8.2 (just an example) myself, and I would like some how makes yum realize that there is a package newer than what the external repos have (GCC 4.4 is the latest in the standard/defualt repos).

It seems like I have to:
1. Create an rpm package myself
2. Create a local yum repo myself
3. Add the rpm package to my local yum repo and somehow specify that it is a newer version of GCC than the one external repos offer

Am I right?

Is there a good tutorial?  I searched online and there are many tutorials for creating RPMs, and tutorials for creating private yum repo.  But I couldn't find an example/tutorial to show me the complete flow...

Any input is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a yum repo. Yum uses the RPM database to see which packages are installed, so if you create a gcc-4.8.2 RPM and install it then Yum will know that gcc-4.8.2 is installed.

Yum understands package version numbers so it will know that gcc-4.8.x newer than gcc-4.4.x